# Need to find a hidden element in arithmetic progression

Tags: javascript, math

I need to write a function to generate an arithmetic progression with one hidden element. After that this function will be called in another one. The user will have to write the missing number. After that he'll be given with the answer, if he is right of wrong. I guess that I should change the entire current function or to add something in the second one.

I've written a function that generates progression and hide one random number, but I have no idea how to find the hidden number and compare it with what the user answers.

```
export function fn() {
  let x = 0;
  let resultString = '';
  const step= getRandom();

  const min = 1;
  const max = 10;
  let index = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  index = Math.floor(index);

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    x += step;
    const isIndex = i === index ? '..' : `${x}`;
    resultString = `${resultString} ${isIndex}`;
  }
  console.log(resultString);
}
```

I expect that I'll be able to find which number is used instead of '..'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the number you hide in a var, and compare it later on with the guessed number.

```js
// I don't know how your getRandom() function works,
// so I created a simple one
function getRandom() {
  return 2
}

function initSeries() {
  let x = 0;
  let resultString = '';
  const step = getRandom();

  const min = 1;
  const max = 10;
  let index = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  index = Math.floor(index);

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    x += step;

    let isIndex = i === index ? '..' : `${x}`;
    if (isIndex === '..') {
      hiddenNumber = x
    }
    resultString = `${resultString} ${isIndex}`;
  }
  document.getElementById('series').innerHTML = resultString
}

let hiddenNumber
initSeries()

document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let msg = ''
  if (document.getElementById('guessed').value == hiddenNumber) {
    msg += 'You guessed right!'
  } else {
    msg += 'Guess again!'
  }
  document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = msg
})

document.getElementById('new').addEventListener('click', function() {
  initSeries()
  document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = ''
})
```

```html
<input id="guessed" type="text" />
<button id="check">CHECK RESULT</button>
<button id="new">NEW SERIES</button><br /><br />
<div id="series"></div>
<div id="success"></div>
```